# Why is the type not compatible?

Tags: abap

I've got a 3-dimension table (table with nested table), and my goal is to remove the lines in the inner table which have `FIELDNAME` equal to `'SCAN_ID'`:

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF ty_cell,
          fieldname TYPE lvc_fname,
        END OF ty_cell,
        ty_celltab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_cell WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES : BEGIN OF ty_line,
          celltab TYPE ty_celltab,
        END OF ty_line,
        zatool_t_doc_input TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_line WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(it_doc_input) = VALUE zatool_t_doc_input( ( celltab = VALUE #( ( fieldname = 'SCAN_ID' ) ) ) ).

DATA(rt_doc_input) = REDUCE zatool_t_doc_input( " <=== line of syntax error
      INIT lt_doc_input = VALUE zatool_t_doc_input( )
      FOR ls_doc_input IN it_doc_input
      NEXT lt_doc_input = VALUE #( 
            BASE ls_doc_input 
            celltab = FILTER #( 
                  ls_doc_input-celltab 
                  WHERE fieldname <> CONV lvc_fname( 'SCAN_ID' ) ) ) ).
```

The compiler gives this syntax error :

> The type of "LS_DOC_INPUT" cannot be converted to the type of "LT_DOC_INPUT"

Where is the error?

Comment: Goodness. Even if you can make this work you should think twice whether to keep it. This is super-unreadable... ;-)

Comment: lt_doc_input = value #( BASE ls_doc_input celltab = FILTER #( ls_doc_input-celltab ... ) ). Can you really use a structure (ls_doc_input) as BASE for a table (lt_doc_input)?

Comment: I have modified the question so that it matches stackoverflow rules (+MCVE). Now it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a "table comprehension" like below, you can get the table with filtered celltabs:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF zatool_t_doc_input_s,
    field1  TYPE c,
    field2  TYPE c,
    celltab TYPE lvc_t_styl,
  END OF zatool_t_doc_input_s,
  zatool_t_doc_input TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zatool_t_doc_input_s WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(it_doc_input) = VALUE zatool_t_doc_input(
                      ( field1 = 'A' field2 = 'B' celltab = VALUE #( ( fieldname = 'SCAN_ID' ) ) )
                      ( field1 = 'C' field2 = 'D' celltab = VALUE #( ( fieldname = 'USER_ID' ) ) )
                      ( field1 = 'C' field2 = 'D' celltab = VALUE #( ( fieldname = 'SCAN_ID' ) ) )
                      ( field1 = 'E' field2 = 'F' celltab = VALUE #( ( fieldname = 'SYST_ID' ) ) )
                     ).

DATA(rt_doc_input) =  VALUE zatool_t_doc_input(
                      FOR ls_doc_input IN it_doc_input (
                        VALUE #( BASE ls_doc_input
                                 celltab = FILTER #( ls_doc_input-celltab
                                           WHERE fieldname <> CONV lvc_fname( 'SCAN_ID' ) ) ) ) ).
```

Regarding the syntax error, as @Florian points out the problem is that when using `BASE` with a structure (in this case `ls_doc_input`), the corresponding `VALUE #(` returns a structure. If VALUE is to return a table, BASE must also use a table.

Regardless, even if you bypass the BASE syntax error with something like this

```
DATA(rt_doc_input) =
  REDUCE #( INIT lt_doc_input = VALUE zatool_t_doc_input( )
            FOR ls_doc_input IN it_doc_input
            NEXT lt_doc_input = VALUE #( ( field1  = ls_doc_input-field1
                                           field2  = ls_doc_input-field2
                                           celltab = FILTER #( ls_doc_input-celltab
                                                     WHERE fieldname <> CONV lvc_fname( 'SCAN_ID' ) ) 
                                       ) ) 
           ). "reduces the original table to a single line (albeit with celltab filtered)
```

or even the equivalent, employing BASE to avoid individual field assignment

```
DATA(rt_doc_input) =
  REDUCE #( INIT lt_doc_input = VALUE zatool_t_doc_input( )
            FOR ls_doc_input IN it_doc_input
            NEXT lt_doc_input =
              VALUE #(
                ( VALUE #( BASE ls_doc_input
                           celltab = FILTER #( ls_doc_input-celltab
                                     WHERE fieldname <> CONV lvc_fname( 'SCAN_ID' ) )
                          ) "VALUE: table line using BASE
                ) " VALUE: table row
              ) "VALUE: table
           ). "reduces the original table to a single line (albeit with celltab filtered)
```

it still won't do what I am guessing you are aiming for since it will reduce `it_doc_input` to a single line.

Comment: You point the right issue (as @florian did), but your solution is to remove BASE so it changes the nature of the OP's code, and you don't exactly answer. Moreover, my bad, I have added some missing part of the code in the question so that to make it a MCVE, at the same time you answered, and you also added some code which was not in the question (+field1, +field2). Maybe you'd like to edit your answer to better fit the question?

Comment: Hi Sandra, my proposed solution is in the second code block. The first code block illustrates how to bypass the error (BASE as @Florian first pointed out) but also that, even if you bypass it, you don't get the intended outcome (table would be reduced to a single row). The additional code (field1 and field2) is there to better reflect zero_coding 's need: I am assuming he's got many fields and wants to skip assigning to each individually.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error: "Unexpected operator <>"

Comment: It's because your `ty_celltab` is HASHED. If you change to `SORTED` it should compile? (I am guessing the OP's actual type is LVC_T_STYL which is sorted).

Comment: My bad, you're correct, I used `hashed` in the edit of the question -> so new edit to use `standard`.

Comment: I also edited my answer to show the proposed solution first